# The most optimal way to generate numbers

Tags: php

How is the most optimal way to generate numbers?

i would like generate numbers like as:

```
1-8  //1
9-16 //2
17-24 //3
25-32 //4
33-40 //5
```

etc

I have variable: $count = 3 so this should show me

```
1-8
9-16
17-24
```

How is the best way for this?

```
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
 echo ??? . '-' . ???
}
```

Comment: `echo $i * 8 + 1 . '-' . ($i + 1) * 8`? Really, this is just multiplication and addition...

Comment: "Most optimal" in what way? Fastest? Most maintainable? Most readable? Do you have any implementation you're particularly unhappy with?

Answer (score 4):

It's more a mathematical problem.

```
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
    echo ($i*8)+1, '-', ($i+1)*8;
}
```

This will output:

```
1-8
9-16
17-24
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for that:

```
<?php

$count = 3;
for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)
{
    echo (($i * 8) + 1) .' - '. (($i+1)*8) . '<br />';
}

?>
```